# How to change the parent of QTreeWidget item

Tags: python, pyqt

How do I change the parent of a of `QTreeWidget` item?

Comment: @eyllanesc here i accidently forgot a word.  I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The process is:

- Get the row number of the item using `indexOfChild()`.
- Remove the item from the parent using `takeChild()` by passing the index.
- Add the item to the new parent.

In the following example, items that are children of the first branch are moved to the second branch.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
    tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
    for i in range(2):
        it = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree_widget.invisibleRootItem(),["{}".format(i)])
        for j in range(4):
            child_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(it, ["{}-{}".format(i, j)])
    tree_widget.expandAll()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(button)
    lay.addWidget(tree_widget)

    def change_parent(item, new_parent):
        old_parent = item.parent()
        ix = old_parent.indexOfChild(item)
        item_without_parent = old_parent.takeChild(ix)
        new_parent.addChild(item_without_parent)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked():
        it = tree_widget.topLevelItem(0)
        if it.childCount() > 0:
            child_item = it.child(0)
            new_parent = tree_widget.topLevelItem(1)
            change_parent(child_item, new_parent)

    button.clicked.connect(on_clicked)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer was very helpful. For C++:
    auto old_parent = this->parent();
    if (old_parent != NULL) {
        auto ix = old_parent->indexOfChild(this);
        auto item_without_parent = old_parent->takeChild(ix);
        top->addChild(item_without_parent);
    }